# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7:site (default-cli): Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

As I am not expert for maven, I'm a bit lost here. We have projects which fail with the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7:site (default-cli) on project xxxx: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7:site failed: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18 -> [Help 1]
```

when executing this command

```
mvn site:site site-deploy -e -U
```

This occurs since we switched to java 8 and to my understanding it is somehow related to [Java 8 and BCEL](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1025). However the message in [the bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1025) is not exactly the same so I am not sure how or what do I have to configure to overcome the problem.

Here the essential info on how we have configured the site-plugin in the parent pom:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.6</version>
<configuration>
    <locales>en</locales>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
        <version>${wagon.webdav.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I tought maybe I should tell maven-site-plugin to use a particular version of commons-lang3 so I added this to the parent pom
`<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.7</version
</dependency>` but this does not really solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a rather stupid error. The issue was with the used clirr which was 2.3

```
08:26:16 [INFO] <<< clirr-maven-plugin:2.3:clirr < compile @ xxxxx <<<
```

Actually clirr was configured in the parent pom to use 2.8

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>clirr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</plugin>
```

However, in the local maven repository there was still an outdated parent pom which refered to 2.3 instead 2.8. Deleting the parent pom from the local repo forced the re-download of the parent pom and now we are using the correct configuration